# How to check screen overlay detected permission in Marshmallow Devices

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-places-api, google-location-services

I have an app in which  after detecting user's location the app displays nearby banks, restaurants etc. Earlier everything was working fine but after a recent update to my Moto X Play device the app asks for 'Screen overlay Detected' and just   crashes. I don't know how to include this permission in my app. Here is my code

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GoogleApiAvailability;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import in.protechlabz.www.yavatmalindicatorserver.R;

/**
 * Created by Nikesh on 03/01/2017.
 */

public class NearbyMainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    private int PROXIMITY_RADIUS = 10000;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private int listItemSelector;
    private String[] choosePlace = new String[] {"hospital","bank","atm","restaurant","gas_station","school","post_office"
            ,"police","pharmacy","airport","gym","movie_theater","courthouse","bakery","bar","cafe"
            ,"car_repair","library","dentist"};
    private AdView mAdView9;
    public final static int PERM_REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAYS = 1234;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.show_places);

        /* Admob related important code*/
        mAdView9 = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView9);
        com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest adRequest = new com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView9.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Extract information from intent for listItemSelector
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            listItemSelector = extras.getInt("PlacesKey");
        }

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            checkLocationPermission();
        }

        //Check if Google Play Services Available or not
        if (!CheckGooglePlayServices()) {
            Log.d("onCreate", "Finishing test case since Google Play Services are not available");
            finish();
        }
        else {
            Log.d("onCreate","Google Play Services available.");
        }

        MapFragment mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map1);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }


    private boolean CheckGooglePlayServices() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                        0).show();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        //Initialize Google Play Services
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                    == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            }
        }
        else {
            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        Log.d("Errors","In On Connected Method");
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
            Log.d("Errors","Requesting Location Services");
        }
    }

    private String getUrl(double latitude, double longitude, String nearbyPlace) {

        StringBuilder googlePlacesUrl = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("location=" + latitude + "," + longitude);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&radius=" + PROXIMITY_RADIUS);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&type=" + nearbyPlace);
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&sensor=true");
        googlePlacesUrl.append("&key=" + "AIzaSyChSLh_uZYL87wFeoNqo7OtupWzFMqYXB0");
        Log.d("getUrl", googlePlacesUrl.toString());
        return (googlePlacesUrl.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "entered");

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
        markerOptions.title("Current Position");
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));
        //Toast.makeText(NearbyMainActivity.this,"Your Current Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d("onLocationChanged", String.format("latitude:%.3f longitude:%.3f",latitude,longitude));

        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Removing Location Updates");
        }
        Log.d("onLocationChanged", "Exit");
        buttonsReplacedMethod();

    }

    private void buttonsReplacedMethod() {

        mMap.clear();
        String url = getUrl(latitude, longitude, choosePlace[listItemSelector]);
        Log.d("Location Value",choosePlace[listItemSelector]);
        Object[] DataTransfer = new Object[2];
        DataTransfer[0] = mMap;
        DataTransfer[1] = url;
        Log.d("onClick", url);
        GetNearbyPlacesData getNearbyPlacesData = new GetNearbyPlacesData();
        getNearbyPlacesData.execute(DataTransfer);
        Toast.makeText(NearbyMainActivity.this,"Nearby " + choosePlace[listItemSelector] + "s", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }

    public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 99;
    public boolean checkLocationPermission(){
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // Asking user if explanation is needed
            if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)) {

                //Prompt the user once explanation has been shown
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);


            } else {
                // No explanation needed, we can request the permission.
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                        new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},
                        MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION);
            }
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    // permission was granted. Do the
                    // contacts-related task you need to do.
                    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                            android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
                            buildGoogleApiClient();
                        }
                        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                    }
                } else {

                    // Permission denied, Disable the functionality that depends on this permission.
                    Toast.makeText(this, "permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know what to do now. The app is working fine in pre Marshmallow devices. But for Marshmallow users this is a very frustrating situation. Please help

This is what I have added and getting null object reference error

```
public void permissionToDrawOverlays() {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {   //Android M Or Over
            if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
                startActivityForResult(intent, PERM_REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAYS);
            }
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == PERM_REQUEST_CODE_DRAW_OVERLAYS) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {   //Android M Or Over
                if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
                    // ADD UI FOR USER TO KNOW THAT UI for SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission was not granted earlier...
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and I have called this method once in onCreate method and next time again in onLocationChanged method

Answer (score 4):

You can use `Settings.canDrawOverlays()` to check if `Application` has the permission, and use `ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION` to lead the App over to Settings screen to further on or off.

add in **Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>
```

**Sample code**

```
public void checkDrawOverlayPermission(Context context) {
    // check if we already  have permission to draw over other apps
    if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(context)) {
        // code
    } else {
        // if not construct intent to request permission
        final Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION,
                Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
        // request permission via start activity for result
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}
```

Inside **onActivityResult** check permission again

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // check if received result code
    // is equal our requested code for draw permission
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        // if so check once again if we have permission
         if (Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
        // continue here - permission was granted

    }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please suggest exactly where should I ask for permission because I already have tried for permission and I am getting error in onStop() method that  Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.disconnect()' on a null object reference

Comment: check not `Null` `if(mGoogleApiClient != null) mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();`

Comment: after above condition I am not getting error but it is not working I mean it just says permission denied and returns

Comment: have you added `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION"/>` in `manifest`

Comment: Have added that permission still toast message appears permission denied and nothing happens

Comment: Dear You are checking for `MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132671/discussion-between-kishore-jethava-and-nikesh-patel).

Comment: how listen event of  on/off button in this ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION screen

Answer (score 0):

As you are showing all data after detecting user's location you can check for Screen detection permission in onLocationChanged(), And if user grant permission then do further operations

Comment: After checking permission in onLocationChanged I am getting this error          Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.disconnect()' on a null object reference